# Native XMLHttpRequest() successfully makes CORS request but jQuery .ajax does not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

Using the vanilla `XMLHttpRequest()` object to make a CORS request succeeds for me, but not using the `jQuery.get()` function. Yet `$.get()` is built on top of `$.ajax()` which is built on top of the browser's `XMLHttpRequest()` object.

Why is my jQuery `.get()` telling me cross-origin-requests are not allowed?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3pwhu05t/

**jQuery()**

```
jQuery.get( {url: 'https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q4231.rdf'});
// or
jQuery.get( {url: 'https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q4231.rdf',
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
          },
    } );
```

**XMLHttpRequest Code** (taken from [this htlm5rocks.com example](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#disqus_thread))

```
// Create the XHR object.
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // XDomainRequest for IE.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

// Make the actual CORS request.
function makeCorsRequest() {
  var url = 'https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q4231.rdf';

  var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
  if (!xhr) {
    alert('CORS not supported');
    return;
  }

  // Response handlers.
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var responseText = xhr.responseText;
    console.log(responseText);
  };

  xhr.onerror = function() {
    alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
  };

  xhr.send();
}


makeCorsRequest();
```

Comment: What browser did you test this in? jQuery doesn't use `XDomainRequest` for IE CORS requests.

Comment: Method 1 works just fine (in chrome), method 2 fails because withCredentials can't be used if the allow origin header is set to `*`. Seems to be working as intended from my point of view.

Comment: typed: `jQuery.get( {url: 'https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q4231.rdf'}).done( function(){ console.log(arguments); });` into the console and works perfectly fine.

Comment: Hmm @KevinB @epascarello , when I use Method 1 in Chrome locally (not on jsFiddle), I am returned `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/.../path/to/js/file/..../[object%20Object]. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

Comment: That error is **VERY** descriptive. `file` is not one of `http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource`

Comment: I'm using the same url when testing locally (`https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q4231.rdf`) 

Hmm the problem seems to be due to using jQuery version 2.1.4 locally. When I switch away from "edge compat" to version 2.1.3 in jsFiddle and use `done()` as @epascarello did, I get the same `[object%20Object]` error in jsFiddle.

Comment: [object%20Object] doesn't look like an error, at least not with the ajax request itself.

Comment: From the error you're getting, it looks like you're trying to send an ajax request to a local resource, not wikidata.org.

Comment: That usage of .get doesn't look correct... investigating..

Comment: Ah,  yes, that syntax was added in jQuery 3.0, earlier version can't use .get({url: etc}), it has to be .get(url) which explains why it's trying to request `./[object Object]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery 3.0 introduced a new way of using `jQuery.get` that allows you to pass in a settings object. This is why the jsfiddle works on edge, but not 2.1.4, and why on your local machine it requests the local file system thus giving you a cors error. If you want to use the `jQuery.get({url: theurl})` syntax, you'll have to use jQuery 3.x, otherwise you should use `jQuery.get(theurl)`